# Term for maths education up to age 18

Tags: soft-question, education

In the UK a school student can study mathematics up to the age of 18 to "A-level standard". In the US, a student can study mathematics up to the same age and this is known as "High School standard" (I believe - I'm British, I may be wrong). Is there a single, vaguely internationally accepted description of this level of mathematical education, ie referring to someone who has studied mathematics at school to age 18?

Comment: In various internet forums (such as StackExchange), I've used "school mathematics" when the audience is multi-national, and as far as I can tell people seem to know what was meant. Keep in mind that these levels can vary quite a bit. For example, in the U.S. there are the minimum HS graduation requirements (varies by state, and even within a state), the level that roughly 50% of the population achieves, the level typical for those pursuing college, the level typical for those seeking to attend a strong university, and the level many in internet math discussion groups seem to think is typical.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro - yes, that sounds reasonable. I guess you could always prefix it with "advanced" or "higher" to stress the subject was studied to age 18 or so. I, wrongly, assumed US high school was equivalent to our (age 16-18) sixth form.